# OpenApi 3.0.2 | Spring Server Generator | Api/Controller interface naming

Tags: spring-mvc, openapi, openapi-generator

I am trying to workout a generated server side Spring MVC code for a  OpenApi 3.0.2 specification.

This is how one of the `paths' look like :-

```
paths:
  /api/v1/int/integrations/{some-path-variable}/some-action:
    get:
      summary: Summary
      description: How to change the generated Api/Controller class name?
      operationId: methodName
      tags:
        - inventory
      parameters:
        - name: Authorization
      other details....
```

The server side code get generated using the Maven plugin which is configured as :-

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>               
        <version>4.1.0</version>           

        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/open-api/myapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                    <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                    <library>spring-boot</library>
                    <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-openapi/spring</output>
                    <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                    <addCompileSourceRoot>true</addCompileSourceRoot>
                    <artifactVersion>${project.version}</artifactVersion>
                    <groupId>com.company.division</groupId>
                    <artifactId>myapi-api</artifactId>
                    <generateApiTests>true</generateApiTests>
                    <modelPackage>com.company.division.myapi.generated.model</modelPackage>
                    <apiPackage>com.company.division.myapi.generated.api</apiPackage>
                    <generateApiDocumentation>true</generateApiDocumentation>

                    <configOptions>
                        <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                        <java8>true</java8>
                        <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                        <reactive>false</reactive>
                        <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                        <performBeanValidation>true</performBeanValidation>
                        <useOptional>false</useOptional>
                        <serviceInterface>true</serviceInterface>
                        <serviceImplementation>false</serviceImplementation>
                    </configOptions>
                </configuration>

            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

As seen in the plugin configuration, I am only interesed in generating the model classes and Spring Controller Interfaces / API interfaces.

**Problem**

For the mentioned OpenAPI spec, the generated MVC Controller inerfaces  is named as `ApiApi`. I am guessing that is derived from the path's begining part. I could get rid of the `/api/v1/int` part but that will generate interface named `IntegrationsApi` but I wan't it to be named say `InventoryApi`. 
What option we have to control the generated controller interface?

Answer (score 24):

> 'useTags' creating interface and controller classnames

Setting `useTags` configOption inside plugin configuration fixed my problem:

```
<configuration>
    <configOptions>
        <useTags>true</useTags>
        <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
        <java8>true</java8>
        <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
        <reactive>false</reactive>
        <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
        <performBeanValidation>true</performBeanValidation>
        <useOptional>false</useOptional>
        <serviceInterface>true</serviceInterface>
        <serviceImplementation>false</serviceImplementation>
    </configOptions>
</configuration>
```

Comment: From command line you could add this parameter appending `--additional-properties=useTags=true`

Comment: Such a neat solution! Why is this not true by default?