# OpenApi-Generator: Generated interface using path (v1/transactions - using v1: V1Api.java - is it possible to set the name in config?

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

My OpenApi specification has versioning baked into the path: v1/transactions

When using the openapi-generator, it uses the path to generate the artifacts, in my case interfaces, and generates the file: V1API.java

Not that big a deal, but when generating Spring controller and delegates, V1Controller.java isn't very meaningful.

Is there a way in the generator to change the name of the generated files? I've tried title, but that doesn't affect the name.

Thanks.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>ransactions-openapi</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
<!--                            <skipValidateSpec>true</skipValidateSpec>-->
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi/transactions-openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <library>spring-boot</library>
                            <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                            <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                            <apiPackage>openapi.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>openapi.model</modelPackage>
                            <supportingFilesToGenerate>
                                ApiUtil.java
                            </supportingFilesToGenerate>
                            <configOptions>
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                <singleContentTypes>true</singleContentTypes>
                                <useSwaggerUI>true</useSwaggerUI>
<!--                                <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>-->
<!--                                <useTags>true</useTags>-->
<!--                                <title>title</title>-->
<!--                                <artifactId>arti</artifactId>-->
                                <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe> <!-- important for Spring Boot 3.x -->
                                <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3> <!-- important for Spring Boot 3.x -->
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: I was able to get the change using getTags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57654685/openapi-3-0-2-spring-server-generator-api-controller-interface-naming